# the Training is stopped for my PyTorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am creating a model to identify names of items in RNN (LITMS)

i get data , then transform data then create Baches then create Model then create train function Correctly but the training is stop here(not working):

[image]

this this my code

```
        for e in range(epochs):
        
            # initialize hidden state
            h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
            
            for x, y in get_batches(data, batch_size, seq_length):
                print ("the login the loob get_batches is succressfuly")
                counter += 1
                
                # One-hot encode our data and make them Torch tensors
                x = one_hot_encode(x, n_chars)
                inputs, targets = torch.from_numpy(x), torch.from_numpy(y)
                
                if(train_on_gpu):
                    inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()

                # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
                # we'd backprop through the entire training history
                h = tuple([each.data for each in h])

                # zero accumulated gradients
                net.zero_grad()
                
                # get the output from the model
                output, h = net(inputs, h)
                
                # calculate the loss and perform backprop
                loss = criterion(output, targets.view(batch_size*seq_length))
                loss.backward()
                # `clip_grad_norm` helps prevent the exploding gradient problem in RNNs / LSTMs.
                nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
                opt.step()
                
                # loss stats
                if counter % print_every == 0:
                    # Get validation loss
                    val_h = net.init_hidden(batch_size)
                    val_losses = []
                    net.eval()
                    for x, y in get_batches(val_data, batch_size, seq_length):
                        # One-hot encode our data and make them Torch tensors
                        x = one_hot_encode(x, n_chars)
                        x, y = torch.from_numpy(x), torch.from_numpy(y)
                        
                        # Creating new variables for the hidden state, otherwise
                        # we'd backprop through the entire training history
                        val_h = tuple([each.data for each in val_h])
                        
                        inputs, targets = x, y
                        if(train_on_gpu):
                            inputs, targets = inputs.cuda(), targets.cuda()

                        output, val_h = net(inputs, val_h)
                        val_loss = criterion(output, targets.view(batch_size*seq_length))
                    
                        val_losses.append(val_loss.item())
                    
                    net.train() # reset to train mode after iterationg through validation data
                    
                    print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, epochs),
                        "Step: {}...".format(counter),
                        "Loss: {:.4f}...".format(loss.item()),
                        "Val Loss: {:.4f}".format(np.mean(val_losses)))
```

I don't know why.

some times i got this error after many trials
[image]

please help me if you can
You can find the notebook file [**here**](https://github.com/youssriaboelseod/problemsForSolve).

Comment: can you provide the error message?

Comment: there arn't any error message , only not any responding from train.py

Comment: after many trial i got error message i add it in topic

Comment: When you say "training is stop here", do you mean there is no print/output and just halt? If there is no error message, chance is the computational resources of your machine are insufficient to carry out the training. Did you try to run your code with a smaller dataset?

Comment: BTW, I saw the printout in `main.ipynb` which looks fine. Do you still have a problem?

Comment: thanks  lpounng  for interesting , sorry i don't attention for your message ,i input the excel sheet named trainData.xls its contain 1833 of rows each word contain from 3:7 words , are you mean i have vanishing gradient problem?

Comment: nope, I was just trying to clarify what you mean by "training is stop here". Is it that the code just runs indefinitely without result? Or is there a result but it is bad? Without details it is difficult to know what the problem is.

Comment: the loop is running without training result

Comment: Then the best thing you can do are to add some prints during training to show the intermediate results in order to pinpoint where the problem is, and to monitor the CPU/GPU/RAM usage to see if there is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: i already add this prins and its result the lopp is stopping in the code which i screenshot it in my topic , and i use gpu and cpu but the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you duplicate this step
[image]

remove it then try again

Comment: yes , this was error , i correct it , but the same , i update my files on githup

Comment: there are mistach when you catch data , don't use .value_counts() in any input to dictionaries to fix encoded ( data.np.array)